# Issue with updating MySql table via R

Tags: mysql, r

What is wrong with given code..

```
dbExecute(con_pratham,paste("Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted=",paste(data_to_update$IsDeleted)," , status =", paste0(data_to_update$status), "where UnitId =",paste(data_to_update$UnitId)))
```

It supposed to update two column **"status"** and **IsDeleted** with respect the its UnitId. Here "data_to_update" is a data frame having 500 observation. each of those row has "Status" and "IsDeleted" along with "UnitId". 
When I just print the above code it perfectly produce around 500 update SQL syntax similar to this..

```
[476] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 0  , status = 1 where UnitId = 56061"
[477] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 0  , status = 1 where UnitId = 56063"
[478] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 0  , status = 1 where UnitId = 56065"
[479] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 1  , status = 0 where UnitId = 56069"
[480] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 1  , status = 0 where UnitId = 56070"
[481] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 1  , status = 1 where UnitId = 56095"
[482] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 0  , status = 1 where UnitId = 56100"
[483] "Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted= 1  , status = 0 where UnitId = 56132"
```

When i just copy any of these sql line and run on server it works fine but not through R. 
Please guide me on this..

Comment: I'm going to guess that `dbExecute()` will only pass one command at a time, so you might need `lapply()` or a `for` loop to pass each command to the database.

Comment: Yes, I just realize that! dbExecute() pass one command at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
sqls <- paste("Update unit_dummy  set isDeleted=",paste(data_to_update$IsDeleted)," , status =", 
  paste0(data_to_update$status), "where UnitId =",paste(data_to_update$UnitId))


for (sql in sqls){
    dbExecute(con_pratham, sql)
}
```